# Who am I? I've been waiting for so long

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

Tommy chased a man to the river’s edge- when he woke up, the man was gone, but he had left a great deal of dirty clothing behind. Tommy dropped his favorite toy in the wash, and all the color bled out. The river was held in a fist, and Tommy titled his toy after one of the fingers (just one, mind you, but a good one). I am second only to that toy’s successor (not by any other name).

Who am I?

(Additional clues for those desiring:)

> The first one was replaced by a new model,
>  The second one’s fatherly brother went down in glory,
>  The third will be me.

Comment: Any more hints or puzzle refinement? I don't think anybody has figured out what you're talking about.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Loose but possible interpretation. You are the...

> Middle finger of the human hand.

Most of the paragraph is describing...

> The word "pinky" (or "pink"). Red fabric is notorious for bleeding (a pun, since blood is red) color onto other clothing in the wash. The other clothes gain a pink color as a result. Also, a "river was held in a fist" could refer to the flow of blood in a person's hand. And a man being chased could be bleeding, if he's running from something dangerous. With the word "pink" in mind, Tommy named his toy after the closest-sounding finger, the pinky finger.

And the last line says...

> To find the pinky's "successor", we move along the hand to the next finger, which is the [ring finger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_finger). If you are second to the ring finger, then you are the next one over, which is the middle finger.

As for the clues...

> 1. First is a thumb. You may be referring to [Tom Thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Thumb_(locomotive)), a famous early version of the modern locomotive train.
>  2. Second is the pointer or index finger. Unsure what "fatherly brother" means. However, a victorious team may hold up their index finger to indicate being "number one".
>  3. Next to the index finger is the middle finger, which matches my earlier interpretation.

As for the title...

> The middle finger is usually the **long**est finger on the hand.

Answer (score 1):

Not the complete answer, but something to start with

> Pinky is the name of the Toy => probably the color that was washed off was Pink

Could not proceed further.